# When does spring mvc decode the query string?

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, urldecode

I have a Spring MVC application which is started by Jetty, and there is such a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/byIds", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> findUsersWithIds(@RequestParam("ids") String idsJson) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(idsJson);
}
```

When I issue this url in browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/byIds?ids={%22userIds%22:[%22123456%22]}
```

I found the `idsJson` in the method is already decoded:

```
{"uerIds":["123456"]}
```

Just wondered when is the query string decoded? Is that done by Spring or Jetty? In some filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet container (here Jetty) does that.

When you call `request.getParameter("x")` (which Spring MVC is bound to do) it will already have been decoded for you.